# Dango bootstrap styling shows up fine on dev-box, not on production

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've got a Django site which uses the "django-machina" forum software, which in its latest incarnation apparently uses Bootstrap4 styling.

After installing the package according to directions, it looks beautiful on my development box.  But, when I deploy exactly the same software on production, Bootstrap obviously isn't running because nothing is properly styled.

There are no 404's and no console messages. *(Yes, I remembered to run `manage.py collectstatic` ...)  There are some stylesheets complaints from Firefox but they're identical in both cases.  But ... the display is not!

Can anyone suggest what I might do in order to solve this problem?  I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Well, once again I answered my own question!

I correctly guessed that, since I was maintaining the remote site from my own box using `rsync`, there might be some garbage left over on the remote side that wasn't being swept-up.  *(I can't use `rsync --delete` for fear of smashing directories that contain images and uploaded materials.)*  I guess it would probably be smarter for me to start using an external repo so that `git` can do for me what it's designed to do ...

But anyway, when I deleted selected directories containing the central and most-often updated directories, then used `rsync` to replace them with clean copies, the interference went away and production now looks correct.